# Vertically centering a view in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to center a `View` vertically on screen with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <EditText 
        android:text="example text"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However it doesn't work. The `EditText` is still at the top of the screen. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

**NOTE:** if I add `center_horizontal` to the `layout_gravity` attribute then it centers it horizontally, but still does not center vertically.

**UPDATE:** using `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on the parent worked. I still don't understand why `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` on the child didn't work.

Comment: i have this exactly problem, like you said in your update.. I'm looking everywhere to find it but no answer.. Have you figured it out yet? By definition, layout_gravity should do what we want but it doesn't work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I track the answer on Google groups, [here it is](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7410e21361bb1b?pli=1) © Romain Guy:

> Well, first of all RelativeLayout ignores layout_gravity. Then you need to know that gravity means "apply gravity to the content of this view" whereas layout_gravity means "apply gravity to this view within its parent." So on a TextView, gravity will align the text within the bounds of the TextView whereas layout_gravity will align the TextView within the bounds of its parent.

Comment: That doesn't seem to conflict with what I'm saying above (especially in the "UPDATE"), but it doesn't work right.

Comment: How is this an answer to the mentioned problem? The OP is not using a RelativeLayout at all, and it doesn't answer why it doesn't work.

Comment: Agree with the above comment, this should not be selected answer

Comment: This is an ok answer because it provides the alternative of setting the gravity on parent to achieve the same result. It sure helped me.

Comment: The more obvious answer is: add android:gravity="center_vertical" to the parent(containing) view

Comment: This may not answer the question but it's a very good explanation about `gravity` vs `layout_gravity`. I'm new to Android so it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways you can center a view vertically. I recommend using the ConstraintLayout now.

### 1. Horizontal LinearLayout

The key is orientation="horizontal". You can't center horizontally for orientation="vertical".

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="example text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## 2. RelativeLayout

With a RelativeLayout you can use `layout_centerVertical="true"`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="example text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## 3. ConstraintLayout

It is easiest to show you this one.

[image]

Here is the XML. It still would need a horizontal constraint to be added.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.constraintlayout.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="example text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple and quick answer is to add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the parent(containing) view. For those who want to know why, please refer to @Bostone 's answer.